# Extracting values from a String containing a HTTP header

Tags: java, http

I'm seeking a better way to extract data from a String that contains a HTTP header. For example, I'd like to get the number 160 from the content length portion of the string: "Content-Length: 160\r\n".

It appears that all the data in the HTTP header is preceded with a name, colon and space, and after the value immediately follows the '\r' and '\n' characters.

At the moment I am doing this:

```
int contentLengthIndex = serverHeader.lastIndexOf("Content-Length: ");
int contentLastIndex = serverHeader.length()-1;
String contentText = serverHeader.substring(contentLengthIndex + 16, contentLastIndex);
contentText = contentText.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
int contentLength = Integer.parseInt(contentText);
```

But it seems messy and it is only good for getting the "Content-Length" at the end of the string. Is there a better more universal solution for extracting values from a String containing a HTTP header that can be adjusted to work for obtaining both int values or String values?

I should also mention that the connection needs to be able return data back to the browser after a request, which from my understanding prevents me from reaping the benefits of using HttpURLConnection.

Comment: how you are getting the headers?

Comment: @SuKu, I'm storing them character by character into a String. I'm away from the code right now but I believe it's through InputStreamReader.

Comment: definitely it has to be some `Reader` but what is the source of that `Reader`,I mean you can proceed using `HttpURLConnection` the way  i have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @SuKu, Unfortunately I can't use HttpURLConnection since I'm going to need to use to the connection to send data back to the requesting browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution will be:

```
new Scanner(serverHeader).useDelimiter("[^\\d]+").nextInt());
```

The other way if you want to create a `Hashtable` of the headers:

```
 String[] fields = serverHeader.trim().split(":");

 String key = fields[0].trim();
 String value = fields[1].trim();
```

I am not sure why you are doing this manual, there is already API for this!

Comment: There seems to be an extra paren.

Comment: This appears as though it will only works for int values of name/value pairs, and it looks as though it'll only work if the "Content-Length" is known to be 160. I'd like to be able to extract by using the name from the name/value if there is a way.

Comment: I used the hard-coded string only as example, just put your variable there.

Comment: @iTech, which API are you referring to? I'm new to this so maybe I'm going about it the wrong way.

Comment: For example if you are using `servlet` you can just call `request.getHeader(headerName)`. The code in your question does not show how you make your connection or if it client or server side

Answer (score 1):

use Class java.net.HttpURLConnection

edited: also methods URLConnection.getContentLength() and URLConnection.getContentLengthLong()

Comment: I have to be able to use the connection to return data back to the browser after processing the GET request and I don't believe a HttpURLConnection allows for that.

Comment: There are methods URLConnection.getContentLength() and URLConnection.getContentLengthLong()
 URL url = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    long connectionLength = connection.getContentLengthLong();

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just stripping all non-numeric characters from the string?

`serverHeader = serverHeader.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");`

Comment: I need to be able to get the value from a name/value pair for String values as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Socket` class to read `HTTP` data i suggest you to use `HttpURLConnection` as it provides you convenient method to parse the `Header Fields`.

It has `public Map getHeaderFields()` method which you can use to get all the fields.

If you want a guide to start using `HttpURLConnection` you can see it [here](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-url-read-contents-httpurl-connection-java).

Comment: I started experimenting with that but ran into problems with sending data. I'm essentially writing a basic web server. Does HttpURLConnection allow you to take a HTTP request and use that connection to send a response that includes data such as an HTML or text file?

Comment: No you can't do that. But take a look here http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=236 . You can use similar method to parse your header.